# Set a bool variable if an element has a class applied

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to hide an element on the page in this way

```
$('.info_player > .item_focus').hide();
```

I need to set a variable on true or false if the element .info_player  has the class .item_focus applied or not.

How to make it with jquery?

Please provide me a sample of code

Comment: If the class .item_focus is not applied, then your jQuery selector won't match anything.

Comment: The element `.info_player > .item_focus` **always** has the class `item_focus`.

Comment: I made an edit to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hasClassItemFocus = $('.info_player > .item_focus').length > 0;
```

`hasClassItemFocus` will be true if .info_player has .item_focus as a class.

Answer (score 1):

You describe different things in your code and description:

```
$('.info_player > .item_focus').hide();
```

means you have the elements like the below

```
...
<div class="info_player">
    <div class="item_focus">
...
```

"if the element .info_player has the class .item_focus applied or not"

means the following:

`div class="info_player item_focus"`

For the latter case you can use `hasClass` method.

In the former case you can use `$('.info_player > .item_focus').length` or `$('.info_player').find('.item_focus').length` and more. Jquery provides multiple ways to do the same things.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jquery` [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
if($('.info_player').hasClass('item_focus'))
{
    var a = value;
}
```

or by one line

```
var a = $('.info_player').hasClass('item_focus') ? "a" : "b";
```

Comment: Why so complex when `.hasClass('item_focus')` return `true` or `false` itself ? `var a = $('.info_player').hasClass('item_focus')` that is quite enough

Comment: `.hasClass` returns `boolean` value. The code above sets the `value` to a `variable` if a element has specified `class`

Comment: indeed, just no need for that, BR :)